# Get Property Decorator's attributes assigned to related property

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I've discovered that I need a way to utilize these two decorators and I'm struggling how.

Basically I'm trying to do 2 things:
1. have a property on 1 class contain metadata over a dataName from one type to a dataName to another type
2. have a method in the same class that looks at that information on the property to figure out how to translate it:

crappy example:

```
class Data {

  @dataMap({word:'cheese', ignore:true}) //filter out
  @dataMap({word:'item', ignore:false}) //filter in
  public mapper[]

  map(){
      // get dataMap info and filter against it

      return filtered mapper array;
  }
}

//setup

const m = new Data();
m.mapper = [];
m.mapper.push("this cheese is bad");
m.mapper.push("this item is good");
const j = m.map();
```

Now I know this isn't the best example, because array's filter can do the job, but this is becoming a large task and mapping to many parts of the system.

I found that I'm struggling on how to write a property decorator that combines storing the metadata of DataMap, and allowing the property to be set (w/o constructor injection of mapper).

Please help (and thanks),
Kelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I discovered the answer...

Prior I was using `Reflect.metadata(target, props)`. Instead I should have used `Reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, props, target, propertyKey)`.

so to add on to the example above:

```
interface IOptions {
  word: string;
  ignore: boolean;
}

const mkey = Symbol('mySpecialProps');

//this is the property decorator
function dataMap(options: IOptions): PropertyDecoratorType {
  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string): any {
      Reflect.defineMetadata(mkey, options, target, propertyKey);
      return target[propertyKey];
  };
}

//this is how to extract that data
function getDataMap(target: any, propertyKey: string){
  return Reflect.getMetadata(mkey, target, propertyKey);
}
```

After that, you would reference in the `map()` method `getDataMap(this, 'mapper')`